# AWS Aurora Read Replicas

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, aws-sdk, amazon-aurora, amazon-eks

We have a couple of microservices running in AWS with help of EKS. So far the data was stored in Oracle database which is on premises. We had a Kafka topic in between microservices and Oracle db.

Now we plan to move to AWS Aurora db and have database also in cloud. So far our micro-services(implemented in spring boot) do not have any cloud specific code meaning AWS SDK integration. So our codebase was cloud agnostic and we plan to keep it that way.

Now we plan to write a new micro-service which will interact with Aurora, so any other service, if they want to read/write data to Aurora, they will call this new service.

For this new micro-service, do we need to use it with AWS SDK? If we just use Aurora URL for data operations, will there be any performance impact as compared to using AWS SDK and using Aurora APIs to deal with data storage/retrieval.

We plan to have one master Aurora Db and 2 read replicas. As I understand write operations will be redirected to master and read operations are redirected to internal LB for read replicas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do we need to use it with AWS SDK

For management operations only. You can't used AWS SDK nor AWS API to actually read and write data from Aurora (you can only do this for Aurora Serverless with [Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html)).

> If we just use Aurora URL for data operations

There is no other choice. You have to use Aurora endpoints.

> As I understand write operations will be redirected to master and read operations are redirected to internal LB for read replicas.

Not automatically. Your write operations must explicit be directed to the writer endpoint. This means that in your app you have to use write endpoint when you write, and reader endpoint when you want to read.

Load balancer for replicas is at connection level, not at operation level. But yes, each connection to a reader endpoint will go to a random replica.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I will appreciate if you could share some link to any articles where Aurora master and read replicas are shown with all the config.

Comment: @azaveri7 No problem. In the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.CreateInstance.html#Aurora.CreateInstance.Settings) there is a list of  all settings for aurora cluster.